# React Native : Prevent touch outside the body image

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I have an Image of the body I am using a `<Image>` Component for that, and I have to mark wound on the body Image, but the thing is I have used `<TouchableOpacity>` for gain touch on the Image. Please Help me out on this. Thanks in advance.[image: Wrong One][image: Right one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg) to render a `path` instead .. which will allow you to handle `onPress` event for the path

```
  <Svg {/**props */}>
   <Path
      d="..." /** Path */
      onPress={() => alert('Pressed!')}
    />
  </Svg>
```

It'll also give you sharper looking image...

Comment: Logic is right, and I have used it in my own way...
but thanks it worked..

Answer (score 0):

The `onPress` handler of `TouchableOpacity` receive a `PressEvent` as parameter. This object contains information about the press location.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressevent